# advice adding some ads

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ads, airpush

I'm trying to add some ads to my unity3d game. Well this is what i have by [default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlkYl.png).

Yeah by default i got some bottoms to activate the banners.

Everything is in C# and this is the example code and original one, I just want to know how to get out of the bottoms and just to show the ads there.

```
 using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;


public class CallAirpush : MonoBehaviour {
    private IntPtr  JavaClass;
    private int     BtnMyAppWall;
    private int     BtnMyIcon;
    private int     BtnBannerAd;
        private int             BtnBanner360;
    IntPtr obj_Activity;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void noAdAvailableListener(string arg){
    Debug.Log("Publisher Call back called:"+arg);
    }

    void onAdCached(string arg){
    Debug.Log("Publisher Call back called:"+arg);
    }

    void onAdError(string arg){
    Debug.Log("Publisher Call back called:"+arg);
    }

    void onSDKIntegrationError(string arg){
    Debug.Log("Publisher Call back called:"+arg);
    }

    void onSmartWallAdClosed(string arg){
    Debug.Log("Publisher Call back called:"+arg);
    }

    void onSmartWallAdShowing(string arg){
    Debug.Log("Publisher Call back called:"+arg);
    }


    void onAdClickListener(string arg){
    Debug.Log("Publisher Call back called:"+arg);
    }
    void onAdExpandedListner(string arg){
    Debug.Log("Publisher Call back called:"+arg);
    }
    void onAdLoadedListener(string arg){
    Debug.Log("Publisher Call back called:"+arg);
    }
    void onAdLoadingListener(string arg){
    Debug.Log("Publisher Call back called:"+arg);
    }
    void onCloseListener(string arg){
    Debug.Log("Publisher Call back called:"+arg);
    }
    void onErrorListener(string arg){
    Debug.Log("Publisher Call back called:"+arg);
    }




    void OnGUI ()
    {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect (100, 200, 300, 120), "Banner 360 Ads"))
        {
            //new Rect(
        //  For ads on top of your screen();

            //AirScript.StartAirBanner360Ad ();

        /// For Banner 360 ads on your screen();
            AirScript.StartAirBanner360Ad();


        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect (100, 350, 300, 120), "Bottom Banner Ads"))
        {
            //new Rect(
        //  For ads on top of your screen();

            //AirScript.startAirBannerAdTop();

        /// For ads on bottom of your screen();
            AirScript.startAirBannerAdBottom(true);
            AirScript.startAirBannerAdTop(false);


        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect (100,500, 300, 120), "Cache smartwall"))
        {
            AirScript.cacheAirSmartWallAd();

        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect (100, 650, 300, 120), "Show Cached smartwall"))
        {
            AirScript.showCachedAirSmartWallAd();

        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect (100, 800, 300, 120), "disableSDK"))
        {
        //If you want to immediately remove banner ad from screen and want to prevent other ads to load then call below method in conjunction with stopAirBannerAdBottom/stopAirBannerAdTop

            AirScript.setSDKStatus("Disable");

        }if (GUI.Button(new Rect (100, 950, 300, 120), "Stop Banner Bottom Ad"))
        {
            AirScript.stopAirBannerAdBottom();

        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect (100, 1100, 300, 120), "EnableSDK"))
        {
        //If you again want to enable SDK

            AirScript.setSDKStatus("EnableSDK");

        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect (100, 1250, 300, 120), "Change GameObject"))
        {
        //If you want to change GameObject

            AirScript.setGameObject("ExampleObject");

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: bottoms? you mean buttons?

Comment: Yeah man, sorry! Buttons!!

Answer (score 0):

Below solution is written on [Airpush integration document](http://manage.airpush.com/docs/index.php?title=Unity3D_plugin_for_Bundle_SDK_1.0): Please refer it.
"If you have added callairpush.cs file to main camera then after running application, you will see few frames added on screen. Ad will be loaded on click of these frames. callairpush.cs file is for demo purpose which is calling below mentioned function on click of frames. You can call these function from your own script on click of your desired buttons. Now you can remove our demo file from maincamera and use your project file."